# How to Unit Test a Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, tdd

My company recently received a new contract in which the client's technologies are Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I've finished learning those, but am really struggling to learn how to do Unit Testing. Since Unit Testing (and then other testing after that) are the primary goals for the first portion of the project, it's crucial that I figure this out.

In all of my research and googling, I've come across technologies such as Rspec, Faker, FactoryBot, Capybara, Launchy, MiniTest, etc. However, I'm not finding anything super helpful with any of it.

Please advise the best gems to use and links to learn, in depth, how to use those gems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A helpful start would be to check out the rails docs for [testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#introduction-to-testing)

Answer (score 1):

Download a large, finished, test-driven Rails app, such as Redmine, and study its tests. Read /Agile Web Development with Rails/ - the seminal book that all those websites assume you have read.

And practice "Test-Driven Development", where you write tests first, and get them to fail for the right reason, before writing new code that passes the tests. This will force your tests to be useful and your code to be decoupled and easy to upgrade, while the whole process resists bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use RSpec and the rest you have already listed. The thing is, Unit tests are not that hard to write anyway. You will be generally testing models and they are pretty straight forward, such as testing validations, attributes, class methods, instance methods, etc.

I would advice to not test private interface of the classes but focus on to test only public methods. Some people, spend unnecessary time to test private interfaces of classes when there is no need.

Other than that, just get into it. You can read about it all day, but dive into it and you will see how it flows.

On top of these, keep your specs small and on point. Make sure to understand the differences between describe, context and it blocks.

One of the companies I respect most in industry is Thoughtbot. Most of these libraries are written by them and maintained actively. Check their source codes to get an idea of their structured test suites.